# Some steps of the turtle graph disappear while using turtle.tracer(False)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

If I do not use `turtle.tracer(False)`, the full image can be shown with the turtle animation. If I use `turtle.tracer(False)`, the image will be incomplete. How can I solve this problem?

```py
import turtle

turtle.setup(800, 600)
turtle.tracer(False) # if i use this function the image is shown incompletely
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.width(2)

turtle.up()
turtle.goto(100, -150)
turtle.down()

"""
drawing
"""

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code shown for a definitive answer but here's a quick fix to try.  Make these final lines:

```
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

instead be:

```
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.tracer(True)
turtle.done()
```

to allow any pending drawing to complete.

Comment: @ChengCow, as I noted in my final comment, `tracer(False)` prevents drawing unless an explicit `update()` or an implicit one (several operations trigger them) happens.  If you don't trigger one at the end, then drawing is left unupdated.  The final turning on of `tracer(True)` triggers that final update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`turtle.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.update) method:

> Perform a TurtleScreen update. To be used when tracer is turned off.

What `tracer(False)` does is it turns of updating the screen. This is useful when you want to draw something very big, that takes a lot of time. So what you do is:

```
Tracer(False)

"""
Drawing
"""

update()
```